# Bash compare strings

Tags: string, bash

I have two json string:

```
test1={
      "id": 12,
      "keys": ["key1","key2"],
      "body": {
        "height": "180cm",
        "wight": "70kg"
      },
      "sport": "ok"
    }

test2={
      "id": 12,
      "keys": ["key2","key1"],
      "body": {
          "height": "180cm"
       }
     }
```

How to compare only "keys" and "body" of those two string?

Comment: What result do you want?

Comment: they are bash variables, just want to know if there are two json variables, and how to compare some key value pairs

Comment: but what should be the result of comparison for these examples?

Comment: I don't have a full answer to propose, but just mentioning that [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is a nice program to deal with JSON in bash, as discussed [here](https://cameronnokes.com/blog/working-with-json-in-bash-using-jq/).